# PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues

Tags: phpexcel

I have developed a program which consists of creating new Excel worksheets containing different cells. The next step would be to generate a vertical bar chart to display various data retrieved from data cells.

All the chart examples work fine, I don't encounter any specific problem, however whenever I try to create my own chart, by calling the `rangeToArray()` and `fromArray()` methods, nothing appears in the worksheet, see the subset of my code below to clarify this issue:

The first step consists of creating a new worksheet containing two cells with 40 data per cell, after that, I retrieve the data from those cells by calling `rangeToArray()` method, then the final step is to call the `fromArray()` method to use these data to create a graph but it does not work, the graph remains empty, I can only display the title and the `yAxisLabel`.

I suspect a problem with the `fromArray()` method but I can't figure out why, could you please help me by giving a similar working example by using this approach? Thanks in advance

```
$retrieve_data = array();

$retrieve_data = $worksheet->rangetoArray("D8:E48",null,null,null);

$worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();   

$objWorksheet = $worksheet;   

$objWorksheet->fromArray($retrieve_data, NULL, 'D8', false);

$dataseriesLabels = array( new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$D$8', null, 1), new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$E$8', null, 1),);

$xAxisTickValues = array( new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$D$8:$D$27', null, 20),);

$dataSeriesValues = array( new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$D$8:$D$27', null, 20), new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$E$8:$E$27', null, 20),);

$series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries( PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART, plotType PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD, range(0, count($dataSeriesValues)-1), $dataseriesLabels, $xAxisTickValues, $dataSeriesValues);

$series->setPlotDirection(PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_COL);

$plotarea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(null, array($series));

$legend = new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, null, false);

$title = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Test Column Chart');

$yAxisLabel = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Value');

$chart = new PHPExcel_Chart( 'chart1', $title, $legend, $plotarea, true, 0, null, $yAxisLabel);

$chart->setTopLeftPosition('G2');

$chart->setBottomRightPosition('S20');

$objWorksheet->addChart($chart);

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');   
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="BAL_Delhaize2012.xlsx"');   
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007'); 
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE); 
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see two obvious problems in the chart definition:

```
$xAxisTickValues = array( 
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$D$8:$D$27', null, 20),
);

$dataSeriesValues = array( 
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$D$8:$D$27', null, 20), 
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$E$8:$E$27', null, 20),
);
```

Should the first set of data series values really be the same as your x-Axis tick values?

```
$series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries( 
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART, 
    plotType PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD, 
    range(0, count($dataSeriesValues)-1), 
    $dataseriesLabels, 
    $xAxisTickValues, 
    $dataSeriesValues
);
```

the word "plotType" should throw a parser error here.

But if you believe that the problem is with the fromArray() method, test that without the chart to confirm that it's doing what you'd expect

Answer (score 0):

Mark,

Oops, I forgot to answer your question. I made a mistake in my example, here's the code about the data series values and the x-Axis tick values:

```
$dataseriesLabels = array(
new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$D$8', null, 1),
new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$E$8', null, 1),);

$xAxisTickValues = array(
new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$D$9:$D$27', null, 20),);
```

The label is located in $D$8 and $E$8 cells, while the data as from $D$9 to $D$27

By the way what is the easiest way to debug a problem with this class when you get no error message?